# How to pass Hive conf with sqoop job

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, apache-tez, hive-configuration

How to pass hive conf parameter with Sqoop import job.

```
SET hive.tez.container.size=4096
```

I am using this hive conf from hive cli every time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-D hive.tez.container.size=4096` option in sqoop command line (you can add many -D options):

```
sqoop import -Dhive.tez.container.size=4096 -Dsomething_else -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx4096m ... other parameters
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<command>[SQOOP-COMMAND]</command>
<arg>[SQOOP-ARGUMENT]</arg>
<file>lib/hive-site.xml</file>
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).